# Simple Graph visualisation with Javascript

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph, graph-drawing

I want to visualize a dynamic graph with JS code, I used Dracula JS, but I can not trigger a click handler on a node with this one ! 
Any idea please ?

I taked a look at this link :

http://bl.ocks.org/tchaymore/1249394

But my graph is dynamic, so how can i replace the 'math_map_compact.json' file of the link example ? Is a string variable acceptable in D3.js ?

Thanks,

Comment: Yes, you can use a variable for the URL to load.

Comment: have you an example please ?

Comment: `d3.json(variableWithUrl, function(data) { ... })`

Comment: Thank you, is it possible to set ' var = variable ' and just modify the variable as a string type ?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. Why don't you just try it?